# перемножение элементов списка

Tags: python

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка.

Хочу написать функцию для перемножения цифр в числе пока оно не станет однозначным:

```
def count(a):
    while len(str(a)) >1 :
        res = 1
        for i in range(len(str(a))):
            res *= int(str(a)[i])
    print(res)

count(999)
```

При первом проходе получается верный ответ 729,
а дальше 81 и 9. 
Почему так получается?

Comment: Возьмите отладчик и смотрите по шагам, что происходит.

Comment: Во-первых, нет табуляции перед while. Во-вторых, как я понимаю, здесь бесконечный цикл. Во-третьих, ты сначала умножаешь 1*9 = 9, потом 9*9 = 81, потом 81*9 = 729. Потом цикл while все повторяет по новой, но уже перемножает 729*9 и т.д.

Comment: @Glebium так вроде, все правильно, но res переустанавливается в 1 на каждой иттерации

Comment: @splash58 Да, ты прав, там переопределение res = 1 и, соответственно, всегда будет выводится 9, 81, 729.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count(a):
    while a >= 10:
        res = 1
        for i in range(len(str(a))):
            res *= int(str(a)[i])
        a = res
    print(res)

count(999)
# вывод 2
```

Ошибка была в том, что вы не изменяли значение `a`, а проверяли лишь изначальное, создавая бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Табуляция не правильная при в ставке на сайт,а вот с тем что не изменял значение спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: `a // 10 != 0`: что вы этим хотите сказать - что a > 10 ? Не слишком ли заковыристо?

Comment: `for i in str(a) :
           res *= int(i)`